# Web Audio API Delay With Feedback Crashing Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, crash, delay, web-audio-api

Everytime I try to run my code with a Feedback Delay, my Chrome Browser crashes, I get that blue screen saying:
"Aw, Snap!
Something went wrong while displaying this webpage. To continue, reload or go to another page."

My code uses this kind of structure:

```
//Create any kind of input (only to test if it works or not);
var oscillator = context.createOscillator();

//Create the delay node and the gain node used on the feedback
var delayNode = context.createDelay();
var feedback = context.createGain();

//Setting the feedback gain
feedback.gain.value = 0.5;

//Make the connections
oscillator.connect(context.destination);
oscillator.connect(delayNode);
delayNode.connect(feedback);
feedback.connect(delayNode);
delayNode.connect(context.destination);//This is where it crashes
```

Comment: What Chrome browser version, and can you show complete code?  Because I use feedback delay loops all the time.  Does it crash on creation of the nodes? start()ing the oscillator?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 31.0.1626.0 dev.
It Crashes exactly when I'm running the last line on the code, delayNode.connect(context.destination).

Comment: This is a video from the actual code running on Debug mode [YouTube Video](http://youtu.be/xsdU-33zShA)

Comment: Wouldn't this be a brutal infinite loop? osc -> delay <-> feedback then delay into destination?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jsantell but, isn't it the way to build feedback delays?

Comment: can you create fiddle using your code that will help better :)

Comment: Sure!! Here we go! http://jsfiddle.net/oliverdrummond/MCnsc/1/
 The steps to recreate the crash are: Uncomment line 304 and 305, press RUN, click on "Ligar Microfone" button, click on "allow" (upright corner) and select "Delay" on the combo box beneath it.

Comment: BTW - If on line 307, instead of connecting to liveInputGainNode I connect the node to context.destination it actually works (even with 304 and 305 uncommented). But I don't think that this is the best way to go...

Comment: Don't you need to give your delay a delay time? Or it really is going to be infinite feedback.

Comment: Actually the DelayNode have a Default value for Delay Time if you don't add one, but on the "real site" I've did gave a delay time for it. Thanks for the tip anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Did you put panner nodes after the delay node?

I had a similar problem.
In my case, it was like a panner nodes' bug.

After debugging for hours, I found this page:
http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-audio-dev/2013Oct/0000.html

It says that connecting panner nodes after delay causes the problem.
If your code actually is like this, it will crash.

```
var pannerNode = context.createPanner();
delayNode.connect(pannerNode);
pannerNode.connect(context.destination);
```

My program was like this code.
When I removed panner node from my program, it worked fine.

So if you're in same occasion, you can avoid the problem by writing panner by youself.
Here is a sample I wrote for my program (in CoffeeScript).

```
class @Panner
constructor: (@ctx) ->
    @in = @ctx.createChannelSplitter(2)
    @out = @ctx.createChannelMerger(2)
    @l = @ctx.createGain()
    @r = @ctx.createGain()
    @in.connect(@l, 0)
    @in.connect(@r, 1)
    @l.connect(@out, 0, 0)
    @r.connect(@out, 0, 1)
    @setPosition(0.5)

connect: (dst) -> @out.connect(dst)

setPosition: (@pos) ->
    @l.gain.value = @pos
    @r.gain.value = 1.0 - @pos
```

I Hope this will help you.